# Upload Conversion Value Rules (Google Ads API) via python sdk / script?

Tags: python, google-ads-api, google-api-python-client

The (relatively) new Google Ads API offers [Conversion Value Rules](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/conversions/conversion-value-rules) - but I am looking for some examples, resources, pointers ... of uploading them via the [python client library](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/). I would like to create potentially hundreds of such custom rules per country / device / ... and would be grateful for some helpful examples of how to do this. Thank you in front.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the type of value rule you're trying to upload?

Comment: i would like to try first something simple like create a `ConversionValueRule` where based on `geo_location_condition` i would `ADD` (or `SET`) a value in the `RuleAction`. Maybe something like the [code here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/conversions/create-conversion-actions#python) but how to set the values based on different geo location